# Simple slideshow jQuery, need it to end after 5 slides. Help?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have a bit of javascript/jQuery which creates a simple slideshow. I'm learning jquery as i go here... and I'm stumped on how to modify this bit of JS to cycle x amount of times before stopping. As of right now it does the slideshow on an infinite loop. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
<script>
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV.item:last');

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow DIV.item:first');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

    $(function() {
        setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `clearTimeout()` after 5 times:

```
var timeout, count = 0, x = 5; // change 5 to the amount of times you want it to go

function slideSwitch()
{

  var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');

  if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV.item:last');

  var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow DIV.item:first');

  $active.addClass('last-active');

  $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
      $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });

  count++;
  if(count == x) clearTimeout(timeout);

}

$(function() {
    timeout = setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

var loop = 0;

function slideSwitch() {

    var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV.item:last');

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow DIV.item:first');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}
    loop++;


    $(function() {
        if(loop < 5){
           setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this version but it was still in the infinite loop. I got a working version as posted by someone else.. but thanks for your time :)